# Starting with a full static html site can I just add an email handler for a single page using Play framework?

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap, playframework-2.0

I'd like to learn Play and I also have to add a Contact form handler to a wrapbootstrap.com template derived static website. I have not found any articles on converting an existing static html website to use Play.

In fact if possible if I can avoid using controllers for each and every static html page I have and only have one for the Contact html form then that would be ideal. Is this possible? Or should I just use the excellent Play tutorials on creating a new dynamic website to learn the framework and separate the email form handler into a small piece of PHP?

Thx.

David

Answer (score 0):

*Learning is good choice ;)*

Why do you want to join PHP to Java frame? it makes perfectly no sense... of course you can try, but in such case maybe it will be better to go with some PHP framework - or even pure PHP at all ? (*note: that's not ironic I'm a PHP webdev as well*) Maybe using *any* framework for this is just a overheat for this task? Even if you'd use Symfony, Cake, FLOW3 or any PHP stuff they all are basing on MVC pattern with models, views and controllers. And that's cool, but maybe too much?

About 'converting' HTML there is nothing special in Play, just put your HTML in some view without any arguments and Play will render it exactly the same with the action. Anyway searching cheap host for displaying this will be a challenge. Personally I'd choose PHP for cents, instead Java for dollars.

And finally answering directly to your question: ***Yes, you can***

Answer (score 0):

You misread my question, using PHP is a fallback if Play is not suitable... It is why I used the word "Or"

Play does not seem suitable for converting a static html bootstrap website with 15 screens to each have a controller when I only want dynamic behaviour for a single one of those 15 screens. I.e. you answered my question, each screen needs a controller even if it is just static html.

Thx.

David